# Stabilizer over G acting on itself by conjugation

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

For elements $g_i, g_j \in G$, the stabilizer of $g_j$ over this group action is the set $\{g_i \in G: g_i g_j g_i^{-1} = g_j\}$. Now, since $g_i g_j g_i^{-1} = g_j \iff g_i = g_j g_i g_j^{-1}$, would it be conclusive to describe the stabilizer as $\{g_i \in G: g_j g_i g_j^{-1} = g_i\}$?

Comment: Yes. This set, called the centralizer of $\{g_j\}$ in $G$, is the set of all elements in G that commute with $g_j$.

Comment: There's no reason to put subscripts on the group elements by the way.

Comment: First statement; you are considering stabilizer of "$g_j$"; then forget about $g_i$; the stabilizer is $\{g\in G\colon gg_ig^{-1}=g_i\}$.